# Maven resources in subfolders incorrectly packaged

Tags: java, maven, resources

I am trying to place resources within the META-INF folder of my JAR-file. So I created a META-INF folder in the resources folder of my maven module. Next, I created a subfolder within this folder called "services" and placed a file in it. But when I am compiling the project with maven, it will create a folder META-INF.services in my target archive instead of a subfolder within the META-INF folder.
How to avoid that?

EDIT #1:

My  configuration:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>

            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>

                <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Are you sure that your structure is : src > main > resources > META-INF > services > yourFile ?
Do you have a specific <build> configuration in your pom ?

Comment: Yeah I am sure. I even tried to pack other files into it to trakc where they get copied, but it stays the same: the folder is META-INF.services.
    Yes I have a build config, I edited my original post!

Comment: Please post the complete POM. The `maven-compiler-plugin` is not responsible for doing that.

Comment: Perhaps a parent pom overrides the behavior of the `maven-jar-plugin` ? What happens if you put a file directly in `resources` or in `resources/META-INF` ? Where are they in the generated jar ?

Comment: Oh nevermind. I don't know why, but for some reason it works now. The second folder was still generated, but I deleted my whole target folder and now only the file in META-INF/services is generated, as expected. The problem is, I don't exactly know which change fixed it, because I didn't deleted my target folder every time. But thanks alot anyways.